# Synchronize "Score" with a timer? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Player score: 100 pts" text with a timer that counts from 50 seconds to 0. I want to make it so every 5 seconds that goes by, 10 points are removed from the "Player score". So every 5 seconds it would be 10, 90, 80, etc.. how can I achieve that? I'm using Unity and coding in C#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreCountdownn : MonoBehaviour
{
    float scoreReductionTime = 5.0f;
    int scoreReductionAmount = 10;
    int maxScore = 100;
    int scoreReduction = 5;
    float timeUntilScoreReduction;
    int currentScore;

    void Start()
    {
        // Set the time until the next score reduction
        timeUntilScoreReduction = scoreReductionTime;
        // Set the current score to the max score
        currentScore = maxScore;
    }
    
    // Can be Update or FixedUpdate depending on your goal
    void Update()
    {
        // Reduce the time until score reduction 
        // by the time interval that has just passed
        timeUntilScoreReduction -= Time.deltaTime;
        
        // If the timeUntilScoreReduction reaches 0 or below, 
        // the score is reduced and the timeUntilScoreReduction 
        // is reset to the next time at which score reduction occurs
        if (timeUntilScoreReduction <= 0.0f)
        {
            currentScore -= scoreReduction;
            timeUntilScoreReduction = scoreReductionTime;
            ScoreCountdown.text = currentScore;
        }

        Debug.Log(timeUntilScoreReduction);
        Debug.Log(currentScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know unity but most game engines has somthing like `update( maybe time as param prolly time since last call but doesn't matter)` ... you can 1. save start system time 2. every time program hits update calculate difference between current time and start time ... 3. taking 1 and 2 into account where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Update` or `FixedUpdate` function, you can access `Time.deltaTime`.
It is the difference in time in seconds since the last call of the `Update` or `FixedUpdate` function. Hence, you can keep track of how much time has passed, by adding up these time intervals between every repetition.

Since you didn't include any code, I'll try to help you with some general code that you can look at for reference.

**EDIT:** The code was altered when the original question was edited to provide more information.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    float scoreReductionTime = 5.0f;
    int scoreReductionAmount = 10;
    int maxScore = 100;
    int scoreReduction = 5;
    float timeUntilScoreReduction;
    int currentScore;

    // You can drag your UI gameobject from the hierarchy 
    // to this field in the editor to link them.
    // That way Unity knows what the gameobject is without 
    // you having to specify it here in the code
    public GameObject ScoreCountdown;

    void Start()
    {
        // Set the time until the next score reduction
        timeUntilScoreReduction = scoreReductionTime;
        // Set the current score to the max score
        currentScore = maxScore;
        // The gameobject has components, one of which is the text component. 
        // You have to access this component and set its text value 
        // to the desired string. Since the currentScore is an integer, 
        // and text is a string, you have to make a string of the integer.
        ScoreCountdown.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentScore.ToString();
    }
    
    // Can be Update or FixedUpdate depending on your goal
    void Update()
    {
        // Reduce the time until score reduction 
        // by the time interval that has just passed
        timeUntilScoreReduction -= Time.deltaTime;
        
        // If the timeUntilScoreReduction reaches 0 or below, 
        // the score is reduced and the timeUntilScoreReduction 
        // is reset to the next time at which score reduction occurs
        if (timeUntilScoreReduction <= 0.0f)
        {
            currentScore -= scoreReduction;
            timeUntilScoreReduction = scoreReductionTime;
            ScoreCountdown.GetComponent<Text>().text = currentScore.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in your question, you said that the score should decrease by 10 every 5 seconds, but then you gave the example of the score decreasing as 95, 90, 85, ... I chose to consider the first statement within the code, with a score reduction of 10 instead of the 5 in the second statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help Aaron. Yes I meant to say remove 10 points every 5 seconds, my bad. I copied your code but the timer is still stuck on 100. Do I need to add anything else to make it work? I'm sorry but I'm very new to Unity and C#

Comment: You can include Debug.Log(timeUntilScoreReduction) and/or Debug.Log(currentScore) to print those values to the Unity console. You should be able to see them change already. When you say the time remains stuck on 100, do you mean the score instead? And if so, are you updating the txt attribute of your UI element? I'm not sure what you're using to display the text on screen so I can't help you specifically. Adding something along the lines of `<variableName>.txt = currentScore;` as an additional line in the `if` code block to update the text value of the UI element should do the trick.

Comment: I'm using a Text UI from Unity to show the score. The name of the object is "CountdownText" so I need to write "<CountdownText>.txt = currentScore;"?

Comment: No, just `CountdownText.text = currentScore;` then. Mind my earlier mistake in writing `.txt`. It should be `.text` instead.

Comment: It says in the console "The name does not exist in the current context". I'll edit my post and put the code there so maybe you could see what is missing.

Comment: Thank you for providing your code, it helps a lot in helping you. The problem is that you do not tell the computer what `ScoreCountdown` is before you access its attributes. What you're doing is in fact the equivalent of asking a friend which color the car is when there has been not a single mention of any car during your conversation. Hence, you first have to **say what ScoreCountdown** is. Next to that, the currentScore is stored as an integer by initializing it with `int`. We need to **convert it to a `String` type** to fit the type of the text attribute. I'll adapt my answer.

Comment: Also, it is probably more efficient if you look for previously provided answers to these questions. Watch some videos, read other people's code, etc. to get the general hang of working with Unity and C#. It will save you and others unnecessary effort. A lot of these basic things have been asked in the past so no need to ask the question again. That being said, I'll still help you out with this one.

Comment: Thank you for everything Aaron! Everything now works like a charm. Thank you for your patience with me! Cheers and I hope you have an amazing rest of the week.